# Return the sum of two optionals or null if at least one of them is absent

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

How can I use the `Java Optional API` to rewrite following code in a more elegant way:

```
first == null || second == null ? null : first + second;
```

The code should return `null` if any of the two variables is `null` or their sum elsewhere.

Comment: You want to use optionals and still return null? What's the problem with the version above?

Comment: If I understand you properly, `first` and `second` are `Optional`s. How is it that you are currently adding them? I assume there must be a `get` happening. What is the underlying type?

Comment: In "if any of two variables is null" "*is* null" is sign of design problem since Optional was supposed to be used *instead* of nulls. Optional can *hold* nothing (be empty), but method returning Optional should never return `null`.

Comment: @Thomas I don't have any particular problem with the code - I'm rather curious if there is any cleaner way to do it.

Comment: @Pshemo You are right. However sometimes we have to break some good practices in order to use external libraries which haven't been designed well.

Comment: @Michael `Integer`?

Comment: Have a look at holi-java's answer. That's one way to do it with optionals though not necessarily cleaner or more elegant.

Comment: @Eugene Hah. I should've considered that.

Comment: The whole point of `Optional` is to get rid of nulls and null checks in your code. So if either `first` or `second` is null, you should return an empty `Optional` instead. This would make holi-java's answer simpler and more readable.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner hi, I agree on your thought, but the OP want to operate the entire expression, so I use `flatMap` instead.

Comment: @holi-java Hi! Yes, I know what you've done in your answer, and it's correct, as per OP's requirements. It's worth mentioning that it would be better to just use the ternary operator, though.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I put my hands in favor, :)

Comment: Are those variables strings or numbers?

Answer (score 12):

I can understand maybe you start to learn how to operate the `Optional`. How about this?

```
String result = 
    Optional.ofNullable(first)
            // v--- the trick is use the `flatMap` here.
            .flatMap(left -> Optional.ofNullable(second).map(right-> left + right))
            .orElse(null);
```

Comment: don't wrap everything with the Optional, it is not its purpose. Is it more **readable** and more **elegant**?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yeah. I agree on. I already said it's for learning purpose.

Comment: While this is what OP wanted, I think it's worth mentioning that the point of `Optional` is to use fewer `null`s, so unwrapping the value with `.orElse(null)` is a code smell.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko that's not the point - and the OP *explicitly* said that

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I've heard that `Optional` shouldn't be used for *method chaining*, however it's the first time I hear that it shouldn't be use to wrap some value. How should we use it, then?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I believe that Andrew meant that wrapping a value only for the sake of using a fancy API is questionable

Comment: @pivovarit The same can be said about using the ternary operator. Why not better use an if/else construct? There are no rules regarding how to solve a problem. Use whatever API you like. If it's expressive, much better, so others can understand your intentions more easily. However, with new APIs, there will always be a gap, because the community is not so used to it. Please do not misunderstand me, I think the ternary operator is the best fit here. It's just that I think that we should give opportunity to new APIs and then choose based only on its factual pros/cons.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner this idea comes straight from Stuart Marks https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej0sss6cq14

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner what do you mean it should not be used for method chaining? Method chaining is the whole clue of the monadic-like APIs

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner it's exactly what AndrewTobilko was referring to at the beginning. Method chaining is not the problem. The problem is wrapping something in an Optional ONLY to play with method chaining. And this is what Rule #4 from the video applies to

Comment: @pivovarit I'm sorry I make it in a bad way. my intention is just for learning purpose. as @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner already said, if you want the elegant way, you should combine the ternary operator & `Optional`.

Comment: @pivovarit I think we both agree, but as Stuart Marks says in the video, you're focusing on the 3/4 empty glass, while I'm focusing on the 1/4 full glass... :) Maybe if I write an answer my point can be understood better

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner just do it, sir. I want to see what's your whole thoughts. I can't open the youtube vedio, :(

Answer (score 4):

If you are taking in nulls and returning nulls, then using `Optional` isn't very useful. You can wrap your code in `Optional`, but it will look just like your normal null checking code with some extra junk hanging around. Using `Optional` just to check for nulls is still just checking for nulls. If you rewrite your whole method to be fully `Optional` aware, you get something like the following:

```
public Optional<Integer> add(Optional<Integer> first, Optional<Integer> second)
{
    return first.flatMap(left -> second.map(right -> left + right))
}
```

Notice how, by making full use of the Optional interface, you no longer need to worry about special processing for null. Additionally, if someone calls your method, the return type is much more specific about what happens on null/empty input.

If the input is out of your control, as you indicated in the comments, you can wrap it in an `Optional` using `Optional.ofNullable`, and then proceed. If both your input and output return type are fixed, then as nice as `Optional` is, you just don't have a good use for it.

Comment: hi, your code can't working. since the type parameter `T` has no bounded type. how do you done the `left+right`?

Comment: I left the type blank, but presumably you'd just replace it with whatever type you're using, or template the method. I'll adjust it to explicitly say Integer though, might be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 3):

If we stick to your requirement:

> The code should return null if any of the two variables is null or their sum elsewhere.

Then you shouldn't use `Optional` at all. It will only make your code less readable and harder to maintain.

The true power of `Optional` doesn't reside in its elegance to avoid null-checks (nor in it's tempting potential to chain methods), but on its expressiveness to encapsulate either a present or an absent value. The best way to use it is as the return value of methods.

In your example, as you are saying that the method should return `null` if either operand is `null`, you are not taking advantage of `Optional`'s potential. On the other hand, if you had a method that returned `Optional` (either empty or with the sum), you would be using it as expected:

```
public Optional<Integer> firstPlusSecond() {
    Optional<Integer> a = Optional.ofNullable(first);
    Optional<Integer> b = Optional.ofNullable(second);

    if (!a.isPresent() || !b.isPresent()) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    return Optional.of(a.get() + b.get());
}
```

This would in fact clearly express your intention, which is that the returned `Optional` is either empty (in case one operand is `null`) or holds the result of `first + second`.

It would be even better if you had *optional getters* for both `first` and `second`:

```
public Optional<Integer> first() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(first);
}

public Optional<Integer> second() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(second);
}
```

This way, the `firstPlusSecond()` method above would now turn to:

```
public Optional<Integer> firstPlusSecond() {
    Optional<Integer> a = first();
    Optional<Integer> b = second();

    if (!a.isPresent() || !b.isPresent()) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    return Optional.of(a.get() + b.get());
}
```

Which, IMO, is much better code.

Or even nicer, as suggested by @holi-java in the comments:

```
public Optional<Integer> firstPlusSecond() {
    Optional<Integer> a = first();
    Optional<Integer> b = second();

    return a.isPresent() && b.isPresent() ? 
            Optional.of(a.get() + b.get()) : 
            Optional.empty();
}
```

---

Or, as again suggested by @holi-java, if you don't want to create optional getters for `first` and `second`, but still want to return an `Optional`, you might do it as follows:

```
public Optional<Integer> firstPlusSecond() {
    return first != null && second != null ? 
            Optional.of(first + second) : 
            Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: I think your approach is the best practice way,  I admit my solution is just only for learning purpose. +1 :)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I *seriously* like how you handle these kind of questions...

Comment: @Eugene Hi, thank you very much. I'm learning to use `Optional` the right way. I used to love chaining methods with it, but Stuart Marks made me change my mind...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I am still on the side to treat it as a NullSafe replacement and I sort of don't care if I chain or not... as long as it is readable and it works.

Comment: @Eugene Yeah, I'm doing the same sometimes. What I don't like is the argument that claims to not use it either this way or the other because Stuart Marks said it in a conference. I believe that every possible usage deserves its own analysis. This time, though, Stuart was absolutely correct and it didn't make sense to use it just for the sake of using it...

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution using java stream

```
private Integer sum(Integer ...additions) {
  return Arrays.stream(additions).filter(Objects::nonNull).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
}
```